# How to pass a url parameter in jsp , if i use request.getParameter('type') i am getting null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, jsp, stored-procedures

I have to pass a url parameter in jsp which will be used in a stored procedure with input parameter `@param`, this param should come from html page which is having a link where I am giving the query param.

But in my jsp page if I use `request.getParameter('type')`, I am getting null and stored procedure param is not set. Please guide me in this

```js
`String type = request.getParameter("type");
out.print(type);
sql = "EXEC dbo.GetDetails @PARAM="+type+",@USER_ID="+ userid +",@OUTResult=null,@OutMessage=null;";`

 .state("link", {
                    url: "/link?type",
                    templateUrl: "views/subscriptions.html",
                    controller: "Xcontroller",
                   
                })
```

```html
<a ui-sref="link({'type':'One'})"  class="ng-binding" href="#/link">
```

Comment: link is coming from different html  page as mentioned above and once it is clicked i need to catch the parameter and pass it to jsp. this is my idea..Please suggest if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

> your request.getParameter('type') is null meaning that in url there is no parameter passed naming 'type'. see the url with ?type='value' if it is not there you are having problems with url.

Answer (score 0):

As you  said you need to send your type parameter which contain URL.

When you are sending that URL value you need to encode with `URLEncoder.encode(partialURL, "UTF-8");` before sending in the JSP.

And once you received using your type paremater using `String type = request.getParameter("type");` you need to decode using `URLDecoder.decode(urlDecodedURL, "UTF-8")`

Please refer below code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String partialURL = "https://www.website.com/document?type=\"http://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology\"";
    String urlDecodedURL=URLEncoder.encode(partialURL, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(urlDecodedURL);
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(urlDecodedURL, "UTF-8"));

}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.